# How do i group for the MAX of a string, while keeping the string instead of its character count?

Tags: mysql, string, group-by, max

How do I turn this

```
 +--------+---------------+           
 | ID     |  name         |           
 |--------|---------------|           
 +   1    | tim           |           
 +-------------------------           
 |   1    | timothy       |           
 +--------++--------------+           
 |   1    | timmy         |           
 +--------|---------------|           
 |   2    | jane          +           
 +--------+---------------+
```

into  this?

```
 +--------+---------------+           
 | ID     |  name         |           
 |--------|---------------|           
 +   1    | timothy       |           
 +-------------------------           
 |   2    | jane          |           
 +--------++--------------+
```

The problem seems to be one of using MAX on a string, while keeping the string and grouping by ID.

FWIW, the table actually has 7K rows and about 40 columns; I don't think that should matter, but I'm mentioning it just in case.

On my existing MAX efforts, I'm getting integers to consolidate, but not strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Id, Name
From MyTable
    Join    (
            Select Id, Max( Char_Length( name ) ) As NameLen
            From MyTable
            Group By Id
            ) As Z
        On Z.Id = MyTable.Id
            And Z.NameLen = Char_Length( MyTable.Name )
```

Of course, this will not handle a scenario like `Rob`, `Bob`. In that case, both would be returned.

Comment: @kelm - It will already do that because it is looking for names within the same ID having the longest length. So "Bobby" being longer than "Bob" it will choose "Bobby" for the same ID. There is no logic by which it knows that Rob, Bob and Bobby are all variants of the same name.